# How to set Listbox DisplayMember and ValueMember using fields of an object?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, listbox

I have a few DTOs that I am using which are designed like this:

```
ProjectPrimitives
   string Name
   int ProjectId

ProjectDetails : ProjectPrimitives
   string ReportName
   string Description
   // Others

Project
   ProjectDetails details
   List<Contact> contacts
   // Some more
```

In my application I have a listbox where I would like to display `Project` objects. Previously, I was displaying `ProjectPrimitives` by doing the following:

```
projectListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
projectListBox.ValueMember = "ProjectId";
projectListBox.DataSource = projects; // This is a List<ProjectPrimitives>
```

However, now that I'm displaying `Project` objects, I can't get this to work. I've tried:

```
projectListBox.DisplayMember = "Details.Name";
projectListBox.ValueMember = "Details.ProjectId";
projectListBox.DataSource = projects; // This is now a List<Project>
```

But that didn't work. All it does is display the object (`MyProject.DTOs.Project`). What can I do to display the name?

**EDIT**

The ProjectPrimitives class:

```
public class ProjectPrimitives
{
   public int ProjectId {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

The Project class:

```
public class Project
{
   public ProjectDetails details = new ProjectDetails();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have to be Properties, not Fields:

```
Public string Name {get; set; }
Public int ProjectId { get; set; }
```

I don't think the DisplayMember property can handle "sub-properties", so you would have to create these properties in your Project class:

```
public class Project {
  public ProjectDetails details = new ProjectDetails();

  public string Name {
    get { return details.Name; }
  }

  public int ProjectId {
    get { return details.ProjectId; }
 }
}
```

WinForms does not have the same breadth of data binding capabilities as WPF.  This is probably one of the those limitations.

Comment: Hm. These are properties though. The first one shouldn't have worked otherwise, right?

Comment: @McAdam331 I don't know.  You obviously didn't post real code, but they look like fields the way you wrote them.  Otherwise, yes, `projectListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";` should have worked.

Comment: I think you're right. In the first one, Name and ProjectId are properties, but in the last one it's just `public ProjectDetails Details = new ProjectDetails();` so that would make it a field, wouldn't it? Probably a dumb question, I'm still new to C#. I'll talk to the one who wrote the code and see how I should handle that. Also, edited question with actual code snippet.

Comment: You context has changed, in your first example you bind a `List<ProjectPrimitives>` now you bind a single (?) `Project` and you are trying to reach the properties of the Details list. I don't think that this is supported in any way. I could be wrong though

Comment: @McAdam331 See [winforms databinding works only on development machine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11023821/719186)

Comment: @Steve no, I'm binding a `List<Project>` I just left out the last line, I'll edit it in. You may be right, perhaps I can't access it. If that's the case, I will have to do some manipulation prior to get the `ProjectPrimitives` objects from each of the `Project`s in the list, which shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: However it is the same problem. ProjectPrimitives is not a base class of Project and you cannot use its properties in the Display/ValueMember.

Comment: You could add two properties to the Project class that manipulate the internal list of ProjectPrimitives of each Project instance to return the values you need to use for the Value/DisplayMember

Comment: That's another good idea that I didn't think of. It's simpler (and faster) than parsing the projectprimitives out of each object to create a new list. Thanks!